# Независимость формы от главного окна

Tags: delphi

Здравствуйте, вопрос очень нубский и я это осознаю, но ответа найти не получается.
Есть библиотека с формой, которую подгружает некое приложение. Так вот - проблема заключается в том, что форма из длл зависима от состояния окна главного приложения. То есть, если подвисает форма главного приложения, подвисает и моя форма, если спрятать главное окно, то прячется и моя форма. Как сделать мою форму независимой от главного окна?
С уважением.

to **Toxicdream**:
Вы считаете, что никак, а у меня лежит чужая длл, которая при подгрузке не зависит от главного окна. Я вам не верю, извините :)

Comment: Вы очень туманно описали свой вопрос. Все зависит от конкретного случая и от того по какому принципу построена система плагинов в конкретном приложении.

Если разработчик основной программы Вы, то посмотрите как подобные вещи делают другие. К примеру, в TotalCmd есть система работы с плагинами и он написан на Delphi. Посмотрите как там это реализовано. В сети есть примеры разработки плагинов под тотал.

Если разработчик основной программы не Вы, то должна быть какая-то документация по разработке dll-плагинов от разработчиков...

Comment: Здравствуйте. Смотрите какое дело. Если я делаю форму на winapi внутри длл - то всё ок, она получается независимой от основного потока процесса. Ежели я создаю новую форму и подключаю к длл, то такая форма зависима от главного потока

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никак. Но если очень надо, то лучше написать отдельную программу, которая будет вызываться из основной и обмениваться с ней данными.